# How to use Knockout.js in asp.net mvc Razor correctly and sufficiently?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

i try to learn knockout.js on asp.net mvc razor. i have been coding below code to learn and test myself
But View side throws me a js error.

Error occurs on "var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));" Error : Microsoft JScript run-time error: 'fromJSON' Unable to get value of the property: the object is empty or undefined

Controllers:

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetGift()
        {
            GiftModel gift = new GiftModel();
            gift.Price = 120;
            gift.Title = "Test";

            return View(gift);
        }

View:    

@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@model knockout1.Models.GiftModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetGift";
}

<h2>GetGift</h2>

<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var initialData =   @Html.Raw( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData);

    $(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
    </script>



<p>Title: <strong data-bind="text: Title"></strong></p>
<p>Price: <strong data-bind="text: Price"></strong></p>
```

But i changed my js codes. Error disappears. i can not understand first usage why doesn't correct? i readed Darin Dimitrov's response:

[Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970951/visual-studio-conditiional-compilation-is-turned-off-error-in-view-when-passin) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonResultData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Me: (it is working good.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function()
   {
      var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));


// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(model);
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message? IN order to use the `ko.mapping.fromJSON` you need to reference the ko mapping plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Microsoft JScript run-time error: 'fromJSON' Unable to get value of the property: the object is empty or undefined   I CHANGED on my Que.

Comment: Yeah, now based on the error message our are definitely missing a script reference to the mapping plugin. You can download from here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output both the min and debug version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message

> 'fromJSON' Unable to get value of the property: the object is empty or undefined

and page setup your problem is that you are trying to use the [KO mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin without including the plugin.

All the methods which are string with `ko.mapping` are part of the mapping plugin and for using them you need to refeence the `knockout.mapping.js` file in your HTML page.

Can you can download mapping plugin from [github](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output)